# TabActivity and getTabHost() aren't working in my eclipse. How to solve these problems?

Tags: android-tabhost, tabactivity

### Here is my code

There're some problems here

1. Why TabActivity is scratch in my eclipse?
2. getTabHost() is getting error? Can anyone fix this code?

I'll try to learn from androidhive.com then i see this tutorial but when I write it in eclipse, it's failed.

```
package com.uavero.androidtablayout;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.TabActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.TabHost;
import android.widget.TabHost.TabSpec;

public class TabLayout extends TabActivity{
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_tab_layout);

    TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();

    // Tab for Photos
    TabSpec photospec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Photos");
    // setting Title and Icon for the Tab
    photospec.setIndicator("Photos", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon_photo_tab));
    Intent photosIntent = new Intent(this, PhotosActivity.class);
    photospec.setContent(photosIntent);

    // Tab for Songs
    TabSpec songspec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Songs");
    songspec.setIndicator("Songs", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon_song_tab));
    Intent songsIntent = new Intent(this, SongsActivity.class);
    songspec.setContent(songsIntent);

    // Tab for Videos
    TabSpec videospec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Videos");
    videospec.setIndicator("Videos", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon_video_tab));
    Intent videosIntent = new Intent(this, VideosActivity.class);
    videospec.setContent(videosIntent);

    // Adding all TabSpec to TabHost
    tabHost.addTab(photospec); // Adding photos tab
    tabHost.addTab(songspec); // Adding songs tab
    tabHost.addTab(videospec); // Adding videos tab
      }


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_tab_layout, menu);
    return true;
          }

     }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can solve this problems. Android 3.0 and Advanced versions does not support TabActivity,
or if you are working with lower versions and still the error occurs then change this line of code;-
TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();, import.app.TabActivity, and
TabHost tabHost = (TabHost)findViewById(R.id.tabhost).